# Center a pin in midpoint of a square with four coordinates (x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3), (x4,y4)

Tags: android

I have successfully mark select a region from my activity based on four coordinates. My question is how can i calculate the midpoint of this square and set an image in the middle of the square region selected.

should i use

ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(this);

To clarify, how can i place an image in the middle of a square in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center is at

```
xmid = (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)/4
ymid = (y1 + y2 + y3 + y4)/4
```

To place an object in the center, you have to subtract half it's size

```
left = (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)/4 - w/2
top = (y1 + y2 + y3 + y4)/4 - h/2
```

Comment: i mean in the center of the square